# isolating a jquery flip function to affect only one item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a deck of cards that flip. The idea is only the one that is clicked should flip, not all of them. How would I reconstruct that logic in the jquery?

Here is the jquery I am using

```
$(".card").flip({
   axis: 'y',
   trigger: 'manual'   
}); 

$(".flip-link").click(function() {
   $(".card").flip(true);       
   $(".card-back").show();      
});

$(".contentContainer").click(function() {
   $(".card").flip(false);      
});
```

You can see the rest on this link to [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/oxrGYL)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're making all elements with class "card" flip on clicking any "flip-link". Update your code to only flip the parent of the clicked link:

```
$(".flip-link").click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".card").flip(true);        
    $(".card-back").show();     
  });


$(".contentContainer").click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".card").flip(false);  
  });
```

See the [updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKBbLw).

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks! Yeah the classes must remain the same because this will be used in a repeater. But this worked flawlessly

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to your script and it work fine : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/p5qr15dk/

```
   $(".card").flip({
    axis: 'y',
    trigger: 'manual'   
  }); 

  $(".flip-link").click(function() {
    $this = $(this).parent().closest('.card');
    $($this).flip(true);        
    $(".card-back", $this).show();

  });

  $(".contentContainer").click(function() {
    $this = $(this).parent().closest('.card');
    $($this).flip(false);       
  });
```

Comment: Good work Ahmed! 3bh beat you to it by seconds and with a slightly smaller solutions. But yours worked great too. +1